# msoffice and libreoffice do not display the height of some fonts properly

Tags: fonts, ms-word, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I wrote 1, 2, 3... a whole page in msword.

[image]

When I load this from libreoffice, the page doesn't fill up.

[image]

At first, I thought it was a problem with line spacing and spacing above/below paragraphs, but the settings were the same.

[image]

So, looking more closely, I found that this problem occurred with a specific font (Korean font), and that the problem did not occur with English fonts such as Arial or Tahoma.

Any way to solve this?

(I'm sorry the image is too big.)

Comment: Fonts are the problem, I guess, cause I use Chinese characters as a similar problem, especially with HanaminA.